# How to load SHOW an interstitial ad in a fragment of an Android app?? New Version of Google ads

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob, interstitial

I've been trying to look for a way to load an interstitial ad in a fragment of my app. Some of you would say why do you want to do that if the insterstitial ad goes between activities? Well in this fragment i have a play button that when I click an interstitial ad pops up before listening. My app has been in an old version of the google ads implementation and I previously used this code in the fragment:

```
loadInterstitialAd(); //when play pressed
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void loadInterstitialAd() {
        if (Config.ENABLE_ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL_ON_PLAY) {
            interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
            interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_unit_id));
            interstitialAd.loadAd(GDPR.getAdRequest(getActivity()));
            interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    interstitialAd.loadAd(GDPR.getAdRequest(getActivity()));
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.d("INFO", "AdMob Interstitial is Disabled");
        }
    }

    private void showInterstitialAd() {
        if (Config.ENABLE_ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL_ON_PLAY) {
            if (interstitialAd != null && interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                if (counter == Config.ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL_ON_PLAY_INTERVAL) {
                    interstitialAd.show();
                    counter = 1;
                } else {
                    counter++;
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("INFO", "Interstitial Ad is Disabled");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("INFO", "AdMob Interstitial is Disabled");
        }
    }
```

With the version 20.0.something this code is not working anymore and i've tried implementing others without successing. The documentation says the code that has to go in there is:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
  private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
        });

    loadAd();

        
        
        
        });

       
    }

  public void loadAd() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    InterstitialAd.load(
        this,
        AD_UNIT_ID,
        adRequest,
        new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
            // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
            // an ad is loaded.
            MyActivity.this.interstitialAd = interstitialAd;
            Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "onAdLoaded()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            interstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(
                new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                  @Override
                  public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    // Called when fullscreen content is dismissed.
                    // Make sure to set your reference to null so you don't
                    // show it a second time.
                    MyActivity.this.interstitialAd = null;
                    Log.d("TAG", "The ad was dismissed.");
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                    // Called when fullscreen content failed to show.
                    // Make sure to set your reference to null so you don't
                    // show it a second time.
                    MyActivity.this.interstitialAd = null;
                    Log.d("TAG", "The ad failed to show.");
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                    // Called when fullscreen content is shown.
                    Log.d("TAG", "The ad was shown.");
                  }
                });
          }

          @Override
          public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
            // Handle the error
            Log.i(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
            interstitialAd = null;

            String error =
                String.format(
                    "domain: %s, code: %d, message: %s",
                    loadAdError.getDomain(), loadAdError.getCode(), loadAdError.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(
                    MyActivity.this, "onAdFailedToLoad() with error: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
          }
        });
  }

  
         
        
    }

   


    private void showInterstitial() {

    
    if (interstitialAd != null) {
      interstitialAd.show(this);
        } else {
            "Cancel or Stop"
        }
    }

    private void play() {
    
    if (interstitialAd == null) {
      loadAd();
        }

  
    }

    
}
```

the problem i think its that it is a fragment but in previous versions as i've shown, it was possible. I NEED IT TO BE IN THE FRAGMENT. THERES NO WAY I CAN CHANGE IT FROM THERE

Comment: Thank you in advance to those who will try to help me, i'm struggling i little bit and i'm an amateur on this

Comment: What problems did you encounter when using the new API in fragment?